# Detailed working of $||f||$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Given $\ell^{\infty} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(a_1,a_2, a_3, ...)=\frac 1{\sqrt {0!}}a_1 + \frac {-1}{\sqrt {1!}}a_2 + \frac 1{\sqrt {2!}}a_3 +... +\frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt {(n-1)!}}a_n$$ Is this a bounded linear functional? If it is, find $||f||$.

---

I am guessing that it is bounded, but how can we tell. And I really need to know how stuff like $||f||$ is found!

Comment: Are you sure about the numerators?

Comment: It is not clear the definition of this functional. Is it an infinite series or a finite sum? In the latter case, everyhting is trivial.

Comment: You didn't alternate the sign for $a_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a = \{a_n\} \in \ell^\infty$, then $\|a\| = \sup\{|a_n|\}$. Now 
$$\begin{align}|f(a)| &=  \left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^na_{n+1}}{\sqrt{n!}}\right|
\\&\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{\sqrt{n!}}\\&\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\|a\|}{\sqrt{n!}} = M\|a\|\end{align}$$
where according to Wolfram Alpha $M \approx 3.46951$ (maybe someone knows a closed form for this value, but I don't). $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n!)^{-1/2}$ can be proven to converge by the ratio test.

Obviously when $a = (1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots)$ we have $|f(a)| = M\|a\|$. Therefore $\|f\| = M$.

Comment: Is ||a|| independent from the summation?

Comment: $\|a\|$ is a constant. It does not depend on $n$, so you can pull it outside the summation that it is in.

Comment: In case the short-hand notation is a problem: by $\{a_n\}$, I actually mean $\{a_n\,:\,n\in \Bbb N\}$ and by $\sup\{|a_n|\}$ I actually mean $\sup\{|a_n|\,:\,n\in \Bbb N\}$. These are common shorthands, but if you haven't encountered them before, they can be confusing. In particular, the definition of $\|a\|$ does not depend on the value of $n$, which only appears as a dummy variable in it.

Comment: So am I right in saying that n is fixed or constant, in these $\{a_n:n \in \mathbb N \}$?

Comment: No. $n$ is a dummy variable. That means that $\{a_n\,:\,n\in\Bbb N\}$ does not depend on $n$. I could equally well use any other variable: $\{a_n\,:\,n\in\Bbb N\} = \{a_k\,:\,k\in\Bbb N\} = \{a_i\,:\,i\in\Bbb N\}$. $n$ is just a placeholder here. This is just the indexed set $a = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots\}$. and $\|a\| = \sup\{|a_n|\}$ is by definition the smallest number $M$ such that for every $i$, $a_i \le M$. It is not a case that $n$ is constant. It is instead a case that it doesn't depend on  $n$ at all.